# RESTful webservice with Spring Boot & Data JPA exposing always the active oracle table

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have three Oracle tables:

1. I_SWAP - with two columns (PRODUCTION_TABLE_NAME,
   BACKUP_TABLE_NAME). This table contain only one record updated daily
   with either PRODUCTION_TABLE_NAME=table_name from p.2 or p.3.
2. I_CUST_DETAILS - filled with customer data
3. I_CUST_DETAILS2 - filled with customer data

I manage to successfuly create a webservice when I mapped directly the table from p.2 or p.3 as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "I_CUST_DETAILS")
public class Client {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PHONE", nullable = true, length = 15)
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "SEGMENT", nullable = true, length = 32)
    private String segment;
...
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/client")
public class ClientController {
    @Autowired
    ClientService clientService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Client> getAllClients() {
        return clientService.getAllClients();
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/{phone}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Optional<Client> getClient(@PathVariable String phone) {
        return this.clientService.getClientByPhone(phone);
    }
...
```

```
@Service
public class ClientService {

        @Autowired
        ClientDao clientDao;

        public List<Client> getAllClients() {
            return this.clientDao.findAll();
        }  
...
```

```
@Repository
public interface ClientDao extends JpaRepository<Client, String> {
}
```

However, the idea is to always expose the PRODCUTION_TALBE_NAME (either I_CUST_DETAILS or I_CUST_DETAILS2) in the webservice and not to hardcode it. How can I do that?

Comment: You can expose it through a custom header of the HTTP response to any RESTful methods of your `/api/client` endpoints. For example `X-Production-Table-Name: I_CUST_DETAILS `

Comment: But I don't know which is the production table name in advance. I want this to be dynamic and to be included in the webservice

Comment: I see it is a spring Boot application. so are using application.properties or yml?

Comment: You can perform `select PRODUCTION_TABLE_NAME from I_SWAP`, can't you?

Comment: @ShubhamKadlag -  I use application.properties

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko - Yes, this is exactly what I want, but to be included in the code/webservice. Aslo can you give me more info/example about custom header of the HTTP response